# Real time sorting of an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, mean

This was an interview question.

"Receives 1000 bids/second for a stock. Want to store the top 50 bids and calculate the mean. How?"

Comment: Calculate the mean of all bids or just the top 50?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You wouldn't "real-time sort".  You would probably use a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) (priority queue) data structure of the top 50 bids so far.  If the next bid is above the min, then you would do a delete min, then insert the new bid.  The priority queue allows you to quickly find the minimum value, delete it, and add a new value.

You can maintain the mean value by adding 1/50th of the difference between the new bid and the departing bid (only when the new bid is better than the 50th highest bid).

Comment: Just to clarify: what's the fast way to find the minimum value in a heap?  The max is easy, but the min would seem to involve a scan of the heap (or at least the leaves) at some point.  Unless you switched things so that the min was the top of the heap...

Comment: You can orient the heap so that either the max or the min are available.  You are saving the 50 highest values.  You order the heap so that min and delete_min are fast.  If you only have a heap that can do a delete_max, you can just store the negative of the bid.

Comment: do you think maintaining heap for each update would be feasible? because for each update i'll have to make a heap and then read the heap by removing the 50 elements.

Comment: @aditya, you would not rebuild the heap, you would only update the heap when a new bid joins the top 50.  If the new bid is not among the current 50 best, then you do nothing.  If it is among the 50 best, you would 1. remove the worst of the 50 from the heap.  2. update the average.  3.  add the new bid to the heap.  The wost-case run time would be 1000 * log(50).  The worst-case would only happen if the bids were sorted from lowest to highest.

Comment: If this will be a semi-long-running app (ie: a desktop, Java, or ASP.net app -- not a PHP script), you can maintain the heap in memory and delete stuff from the DB (if you insist on having one) as it's removed from the heap.  If the table only has 50 rows, a delete should be pretty fast.  But as for the heap, you don't really need to remove elements to read them -- most heap stuff gives you the ability to get an array containing the elements, if not actually set it.

Comment: don't you have to add instead of subtract the difference? (think about mean value has to increase not decrease)